# Cmake how to selectively include folders

Tags: c++, cmake

I am experiencing a problem in including only some folders in my cmake target_include_directories.
I need to include all but the folder `/include/ros` in the include directory if a CMake option is **OFF** and all, include that folder, if **ON**

The project look like this:

```
- include
  - core
  - algorithms 
  - ros
- src
  - core 
  - algorithms
  - CMakeLists.txt
- CMakeLists.txt
```

What is the best way to do so?

After playing around with it and thanks to the help I received in the comments I have moved forward but now I ended up having the following error:

```
CMake Error in src/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "myLib" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path:

    "/home/dario/myLib/src/"

  which is prefixed in the source directory.


-- Generating done
```

The relevant part of the CMake where I believe the problem to be looks like the following:

```
    # There are two diffent installation whether BUILD_ROS is enabled or not

# generate the lists of generate includes
list(APPEND includeSources 
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/core"
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/algorithms"
  )
list(APPEND includeBinaries 
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/core"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/algorithms"
  )
# add a line if BUILD_ROS is included
if(BUILD_ROS)
  list(APPEND includeSources 
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ros"
    )
  list(APPEND includeBinaries 
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/ros"
    )
endif()

# now do target include
target_include_directories(myLib
  PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:"${includeSources};${includeBinaries}">
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  PRIVATE
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )
```

The output of the

```
get_target_property(debug myLib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("${debug}")
```

is the following:

```
/home/dario/myLib/src/$<BUILD_INTERFACE:"/home/dario/myLib/src/include/core;/home/dario/myLib/src/include/algorithms;/home/dario/myLib/build/src/include/core;/home/dario/myLib/build/src/include/algorithms">;$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
```

where you can easily see that there is `/home/dario/myLib/src` prefixed.

Now what I cannot understand is why that is there, if, for instance, I call the `BUILD_INTERFACE` macro in the `target_include_directories` with only `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include` everything runs smoothly and no error appears. But, if I try to add more than one folder then it appends the src folder (that is where the CMakeLists.txt giving the error is btw).

Comment: Maybe some environment variable changed for your session of terminal/OS?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I rebooted the computer as well and did not set any variable myself, literally just make, fixed a typo in a function call and make again.

Comment: Most likely, it is something wrong with your project. But we cannot help you without viewing into that project. The fact that project worked in the past doesn't mean that the project is correct. Note, that we don't want your complete project. Instead, we want [mcve]. If you want to debug original project by yourself, I would suggest to pass additional `VERBOSE=1` option to `make` and closely inspect `-I` options passed to the compiler. Check that one of these options actually specifies a directory, which contains missed header (`mylib/core/state_position.h` in your case).

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev I now moved on and I am able to understand what is the problem. I still do not have a solution for it tho. I have updated the question

Comment: So, when `BUILD_ROS` variable is set to TRUE, then everything is succeed. When this variable is set to FALSE, then you get the error. Am I correctly understand your situation? Which include directory in the `if(BUILD_ROS)` branch contains the header (`mylib/core/state_position.h`)? Why don't you specify this directory in the `else` branch?

Comment: That is correct, that is the situation. 
The directory containing the state_position is actually specified in the else branch, is the first one in the list.

Comment: Most likely, the directory `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mylib/core` **immediately** contains the header `state_position.h`, so `#include <state_position.h>` will work. But for `#include <mylib/core/state_position.h>` to work, you need to specify `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include` as include directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see. And is there a way to avoid replacing all the includes and make it generic in the CMake? Just ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include will not work since I have to exclude one directory for the subdirs in include

Comment: Just do NOT put into a **single directory** the header files, which inclusion you want to allow **selectively**. E.g. you could have a header `core/include/mylib/core/state_position.h`, so it will be accessible (via `#include <mylib/core/state_position.h>`) only when you add `core/include` include directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem that sticks out is that you're thinking about your dependencies in terms of folder you need to include instead of the cmake targets that they need to be.

cmake targets specifies dependencies that themselves include dedicated settings such as which headers to include, which dependencies they have, and even which C++ features they require.

With this in mind, consider moving `ros` to a dedicated subproject to be conditionally included in your base project depending on how you configure it.  This approach consists of:

- converting `ros` into a subproject intended to be included conditionally,
- update your base project to conditionally include `ros` as dependency,
- provide a config file to use in your source code to determine whether a source file can or cannot include things from `ros`.

Take, for example:

```
- CMakeLists.txt    // root project which includes baseproj and ros as subprojects
- ros               // the newly-added optional project
  - include
    - ros
  - CMakeLists.txt
- baseproj          // the original project without ros stuf
  - include
    - core
    - algorithms 
  - src
    - core 
    - algorithms
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - config.h.in     // config file that provides definitions to check if ros
```

In this scenario, let's assume that `ros` is a headers-only library.  In this case, `./ros/CMakeLists.txt` would be something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(ros)

add_library(ros INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(ros
  INTERFACE 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
```

On `./CMakeLists.txt` you can include `ros` conditionally.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

add_subdirectory(baseproj)

option(USE_ROS "Build with ros or not" YES)
if(USE_ROS)
    add_subdirectory(ros)
endif()
```

On `./baseproj/CMakeLists.txt` ros needs to included conditionally as a build target.

```
# This is where you've added your add_library() and/or add_executable()
#...
    if(USE_ROS)
        target_link_library(baseproj    # 
            PRIVATE
                ros
    endif()
#...
```

Finally, you need to provide a config file that includes definitions referrable from baseproj's source code.  Here is the content of `./baseproj/config.h.in`:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define USE_ROS "${USE_ROS}"

#endif
```

For cmake to generate `config.h` from `config.h.in` then the cmake project needs to call `configure_file`.  Thus the following call should be featured in `./baseproj/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# ...

configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in" 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h"
)

# ...
```

Subsequently, just include the resulting `config.h` in your source code, and check `USE_ROS` to determine if the source file is supposed to include stuff from `ros` or not.